# How much are Or How much do?

Tags: grammar

I know that we usually say "how much does it cost" when asking for a price.

But today, I heard someone said "how much are the kidney beans?" in a store, and I don't think it's correct.

**Does "How much are the kidney beans?" equal "How much do the kidney beans cost?"?**

Comment: Yes, they mean the same thing, and it’s perfectly correct. See [the ODO definition of the verb _be_](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/be) (sense 3.1). In fact, especially with a specific subject, it is by far the more common of the two ways to ask for a price: “How much are the kidney beans?” is much more common than “How much do the kidney beans costs?”. Note that questions that can be answered by a simple dictionary lookup [are considered off-topic here](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet - “How much do the kidney beans costs?” - Of course you meant "cost" (plural) there.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Bugger! Yes, _costs_ was a typo; curse that five-minute edit window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The Oxford English Dictionary, in [its definition of be](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/be), has:

> 3 *[as copular verb]* Having the state, quality, identity, nature, role, etc., specified.
>
> …
>
> 3.1 Cost.
>
> > ‘the tickets were £25’

In the Oxford Advanced American Dictionary, the [definition of be](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/be_1?q=be) includes:

> 13 *linking verb* **+ noun** to cost
>
> > “How much is that dress?” “Eighty dollars.”

The first popular culture reference that springs to mind is “[(How Much Is) That Doggie in the Window?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(How_Much_Is)_That_Doggie_in_the_Window%3F)”.

Comment: +1 for the doggie in the window - the first thing I thought of when I saw the question.